# The number of real roots of the equation

Tags: exponential-function, roots, quadratics

> $$e^{\sin x}-e^{-\sin x}-4=0$$

Let $e^{\sin x}=y$

Then $$y-\frac 1y -4=0$$
$$y^2-4y-1=0$$
$$y=2+\sqrt 5 , 2-\sqrt 5$$

How should I solve further ?

Comment: **Hint:** Try Using logarithms.

Comment: $e^{-1}\leq e^{\sin x}\leq e^1$

Comment: No real roots. Got it!

Answer (score 4):

Your method is fine, now observe that

- $e^{\sin x}=2+\sqrt 5 \implies \sin  x=\log(2+\sqrt 5)>1$

which is not possible and

- $e^{\sin x}=2-\sqrt 5<0 $

which is not possible, therefore there are not real solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$e^{\sin x}-e^{-\sin x}-4 \le e-e^{-\sin x}-4<0.$ Hence, the equation has no real roots !